# Exclude Application from Launcher

Tags: android, launcher

How do I exclude an application from appearring in the Application Launcher. The code below is used to add on to the launcher but when I exclude it, the launcher still appears.

```
<activity android:name=".Application" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the [`android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) category:

```
<activity android:name=".Application" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: And depending on how you want your app to be launched you may omit the `intent-filter` all together.  If you only want it to be launched by calling out the specific class it's unneeded.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. 
I'll give some more detail which will convolute this even further. 
That Application class is actually contained in an Android Library  project used by another application. I had removed the Launcher category but it still appearred. In fact I emptied the manifest file like this:

   <activity android:name=".Application"  android:label="@string/app_name"> </activity>

Now I have even made the application class abstract and it is extended by the Main class of the non-library app. I still have a launcher with the library name.

Comment: @androider: Then there is some problem with your library project and how it is being incorporated into the parent project.